# Migrating Wysiwyg/Ckeditor embedded images to embeded images

Tags: migrations, wysiwyg, 9

I am migrating a Drupal 7 site that is using:
drupal/wysiwyg:^2.9' (plus the ckeditor library)
drupal/media:^2.27'
drupal/media_ckeditor:^2.14'

In Drupal 7, when you insert an image into the wysiwyg body. The source code looks like this.

```
[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_large","fid":"532","field_deltas":{"1": 
{}},"link_text":null,"fields":{},"attributes":{"alt":"Image of a hand","height":"238","width":"278","style":"margin: 10px; width: 278px; height: 238px; 
float: right;","class":"media-image media-element file-media-large","data-delta":"1"}}]]
```

After migrating this site to Drupal 9 using drush. This source code still looks the same. Is there a way to convert this markup to the Drupal 9 embedded image markup. Which looks simular to this.

```
 <drupal-entity alt="uil" data-embed-button="file_browser" data-entity-embed- 
 display="image:image" data-entity-embed-display-settings=" 
 {&quot;image_style&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_link&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" data-entity- type="file"
 data-entity-uuid="380923a6-e8b4-4b44-b0e5-c8d807aa6fef" data-langcode="en"> </drupal-entity>
```

Do I need to use this module on the Drupal 9 site?
https://www.drupal.org/project/media_migration

Comment: Does this help ? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/307378/how-do-i-migrate-body-content-with-embed-embed-tags/307397#307397

Comment: Trying this next https://www.drupal.org/node/3135434

Answer (score 1):

Use module
https://www.drupal.org/project/media_migration

Open your settings.php file and add this:

```
// Using module - Media Migration - use method - media_embed and uuid
// https://www.drupal.org/node/3135434
$settings['media_migration_embed_token_transform_destination_filter_plugin'] = 'media_embed';
// force using data-entity-uuid instead of data-entity-id
$settings['media_migration_embed_media_reference_method'] = 'uuid';
```

Go to your text format and checkbox tick 'Embed media'. Set it to use ckeditor
Drag the media button onto the active toolbar.It is okay to check and use these filters:Align images, Caption images, Track images uploaded via a Text Editor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem.  Tried https://www.drupal.org/project/media_migration but just couldn't seem to get it to work.  So, I went old school.  I figured that I could write a migration source plugin that would take this:

```
[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_large","fid":"532","field_deltas":{"1": 
{}},"link_text":null,"fields":{},"attributes":{"alt":"Image of a hand","height":"238","width":"278","style":"margin: 10px; width: 278px; height: 238px; 
float: right;","class":"media-image media-element file-media-large","data-delta":"1"}}]]
```

And convert it to a ckeditor compatible D9 image link.

In my migration module, I created two functions:

```
<?php
/**
* Get the inline image link info for this fid
*
* Requires: fid
*
* Returns an array with the FileName, UUID and RealPath for the fid image
*
* Array containing uuid, filename and realpath to file
*
* Array
* (
* [uuid] => 2a8c2c69-7cc9-43cd-9d79-3ee22e59c0a7
* [filename] => node label - hidden.jpg
* [path] => /var/www/html/websites/drupal9/master1and1/private/master1and1/node label - hidden.jpg
* )
*
*/
function sbn_migrations_get_image_link_info($fid) {

 $link_info = [];

$database = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default', 'default');

$query = $database->select('file_managed', 'fm');
$query->condition('fm.fid', $fid, '='); // Find this fid
$query->fields('fm', ['uri']);
$query->fields('fm', ['uuid']);
$query->fields('fm', ['filename']);
$result = $query->execute();
foreach ($result as $record) {
$link_info['uuid'] = $record->uuid;
$link_info['filename'] = $record->filename;
  $uri = $record->uri;
  $link_info['path'] = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($uri);
$link_info['path'] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $link_info['path']);  
}

return $link_info;
}
/**
* Insert the correctly formatted D9 link into text body
*
* Requires: body text field
*
* Returns updated body text field with correct links (if necessary)
*
*
*/
function sbn_migrations_insert_link_into_body($body) {

$body;
$array = [];
$pattern = '/\[\[[^\]]+\"fid\"\:\"([0-9]+)\"\,[^\]]+\]\]/i';

preg_match_all($pattern, $body, $array); // search for the d7 code
// dpm($array); // Test
if (empty($array)) return $body; // if no code is found, return the $body

// If code is found, we continue on.

foreach ($array[1] as $key => $fid) {

$link_info = sbn_migrations_get_image_link_info($fid); // get the link information for this $fid
// Only continue processing if something is returned
if (!empty($link_info) && !is_null($link_info)) {
// Create the link
  $link = '<img alt="'.$link_info['filename'].'" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="'.$link_info['uuid'].'" src="'.$link_info['path'].'" />';
  $pattern01 = '/(\[\[)[^\]]+\"fid\"\:\"('.$fid.')\"\,[^\]]+(\]\])/i'; // this is the pattern for replacing links in the body text
  $replacement = $link; // this will be the the new $link replacing the old code.
  $body = preg_replace($pattern01, $replacement, $body); // this is the new body text
  \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus('(info) insert link into body processing fid value '.$fid.' | '.$link_info['filename']);
 
}
}
return $body;
}
?>
```

Then, in the **prepareRow()** section of my source plugin, I added this:

```
<?php
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function prepareRow(Row $row) {

// Check the $body_value for inline image links
$body_value = $row->getSourceProperty('body_value');
$body_value = sbn_migrations_insert_link_into_body($body_value); // Check body for image links
$row->setSourceProperty('body_value', $body_value);

return parent::prepareRow($row);
}

?>
```

Essentially, I am scanning the body text of my source input and replacing the D7 ckeditor image links with D9 formatted links.  I use php regex functions **preg_replace()** and **preg_match_all()**  to find the old code and replace it with new.

This works because the files referenced in the D7 links are migrated by the Drupal d7_file migration and they are in the correct public/private locations.  I use `\Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($uri)`, create the new D9 (standard html) link, and I'm in business.

Just sharing an alternate method for getting this done.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a simple migrate process plugin, like this:

```
namespace Drupal\your_migrate\Plugin\migrate\process;

use Drupal\migrate\Annotation\MigrateProcessPlugin;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\ProcessPluginBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;

/**
 * Converts the media embed from D7 to D10 media embed in body
 *
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "body_with_embed_media"
 * )
 */
class BodyWithEmbedMedia extends ProcessPluginBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {
  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    public $entity_type_manager,
    public $file_usage,
  ) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition): BodyWithEmbedMedia|static {
    return new static (
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
     $container->get('file.usage'),
    );
  }

  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property): array {
    $text = $value['value'];
    if (preg_match_all('/\[\[\{"fid":"(\d+)".*?\]\]/m', $text, $matches) > 0) {
      $replacements = [];
      foreach ($matches[1] as $id => $fid) {
        $file = $this->entity_type_manager->getStorage('file')->load($fid);
        $result = $this->file_usage->listUsage($file);
        $media_id = array_keys($result['file']['media'])[0];
        $media = $this->entity_type_manager->getStorage('media')->load($media_id);
        $replacements[$id] = 'uuid() . '"> ';
      }
      $value['value'] = str_replace($matches[0], $replacements, $value['value']);
    }
    return $value;
  }
}
```

And in your migration yaml in the process section you'll just use it like this:

```
  body:
    -
      plugin: body_with_embed_media
      source: body
```

**Warning! This code will only works with PHP 8.2 and higher.** To make it work in PHP versions lower than 8.2 you need to get rid of the constructor property promotion (https://stitcher.io/blog/constructor-promotion-in-php-8)